# How Can I Initialize an object with help of properties of initializing object in VBA

Tags: vba, oop, excel, factory, factory-pattern

I have two objects that need to interact with each other one is called `Collateral` the other is called `Model`. `Model` is an abstract Class is implemented by `Model_A`, `Model_B`, `Model_AB`. Each Collateral object has a collection of `models` as one of its properties. In order to initialize each `Model` I will need to use information from `Collateral`(and still another object lets call it `User_Input`), that information will vary with implementation of `Model`.

My question is it possible to use a constructor that will be aware of what object is creating it(in this case `Model` Constructor that knows what `Collateral` instantiated it)?
If not I assume that someone will suggest for me to use abstract factory pattern, if so is so how would it look like(I'm afraid I'm still green when it comes to OOP)?

For Simplicity's sake assume following:

- `Collateral` has properties A, B, C , Models_Collection
- `Collateral` Calls procedure `Run` for Each of `Models` it created( has in Models_Collection)
- `Model` has a public Sub called `Run` which is implemented in all classes bellow
- Procedure `Run` Manipulates `Collateral`
- `Model_A` requires property A to initialize
- `Model_B` requires property B to initialize
- `Model_AB` requires property A, B to initialize

Here is a Simplified Code of how I assume this should look like:

Collateral

```
Dim A, B, C as Variant
Dim Model_Collection as Collection
Sub New_Model( Model_Type as String)
    Model_Collection.Add(Model_Implementation)
End Sub
Sub Execute_Models()
    For Each Model in Model_Collection
        Model.Run(Me)
    Next Model
End Sub
```

Model

```
    Sub Run()
    End
```

Model_A

```
Implements Model
Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Some code that takes property A from Collateral that Created this object
Sub Run(Collateral as Collateral)
    'Some Code
End Sub
```

Model_B

```
Implements Model
Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Some code that takes property B from Collateral that Created this object
Sub Run(Collateral as Collateral)
    'Some Code
End Sub
```

Model_AB

```
Implements Model
Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Some code that takes property A, and B from Collateral that Created this object
Sub Run(Collateral as Collateral)
    'Some Code
End Sub
```

Comment: I like what you're doing - OOP in VBA is always nice to see. VBA has no constructors, so you're right, you'll need factories; `Class_Initialize` cannot be parameterized, and runs before any other code in the class - so you can't use it as a constructor.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit. You want `Collateral` to create the `Model` objects? Would it be acceptable to create them outside of `Collateral` and pass them into it?

Comment: Mat's Mug: Thanks for prompt response, whould you be able to suggest what the factory(ies) would look like

Comment: RubberDuck: per Mat's Mug's observation it looks like I'll have to do that

Comment: @sgp667 I've favorited this post, I'll come back to it in a few hours if it's not answered yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets answer your question. How can you dynamically create instances of different class that all implement the same interface? As was pointed out, VBA doesn't have any constructors, so you're correct. A Factory Pattern is called for here.

How I tend to go about this is define a public enum in the Interface class that keeps track of what classes have been implemented. Any time you implement a new one, you'll need to add it to your enum and Factory. It's a bit more maintenance then I like, but without proper reflection, there's not much we can do about that.

So, the `IModel` interface:

```
Public Enum EModel
    ModelA
    ModelB
    ModelC
End Enum

Public Sub Run
End Sub
```

Your models themselves remain unchanged. Then back in your `Collateral` implement your `New_Model` like this.

```
private models as Collection

Public Sub New_Model(ByVal type As EModel) As IModel
    dim model As IModel
    Select Case type
        Case EModel.ModelA: Set model = New ModelA
        Case EModel.ModelB: Set model = New ModelB
        Case EModel.ModelC: Set model = New ModelC
    End Select

    models.Add model
End Sub
```

Note that it's better to use the enum than a string as in your example so it gets compile time checked for errors instead of runtime. (This removes the chances of misspelling something.)

---

If it was me implementing this, I would create an actual separate class `ModelFactory`. Then `Collateral` would call on the model factory to get what it needs. It makes a nice separation of concerns I think.

An implementation would look something like this, based on your requirements.

```
 Public Function CreateModel(Optional A As Variant, Optional B As Variant, Optional C As Variant)
     If Not A Is Nothing Then
         If B Is Nothing Then
             Set CreateModel = New ModelA
             Exit Function
         Else
             Set CreateModel = New ModelC
             Exit Function
         End If
     End If

     If Not B Is Nothing Then
         Set CreateModel = New ModelB
         Exit Function
     End If
 End Function
```

Note that this entirely does away with the enum and the need to specify the type. The factory knows what to create based on which arguments are available to it.

Then your `Collateral` class simply calls on the factory and gives it whatever it has.

```
Private A,B,C
Private models As Collection
Private factory As ModelFactory

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set factory = New ModelFactory
End Sub

Public Sub New_Model()
    models.Add factory.CreateModel(A,B,C)
End Sub
```

---

Now, I'm going to pre-emptively answer your next question, because I feel like you're on the verge of asking it already.

> How can I tell exactly what type of model I have?

Well, for that you have a few options that are detailed a bit in [this code review Q & A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63353/traversing-and-printing-complex-dictionary-types-scripting-dictionary-dictio). It depends on your use case, but here they are.

- `TypeName(arg)` - Returns the string name of the object. For example:

  ```
  Dim model As IModel
  Set model = New ModelA

  Debug.Print TypeName(model) '=> "ModelA"
  ```
- `TypeOf` and `Is` - Checks the type of a variable a bit more strongly. Details are in the question I linked to, but here is an example.

  ```
  Dim model as IModel
  Set model = SomeFunctionThatReturnsAnIModel()

  If TypeOf model Is ModelA Then
      ' take some specific action for ModelA types
  Else If TypeOf model Is ModelB Then
      ' ModelB type specific action
  Else If ...
  ```